# process records sequentially in Mule batch

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I have around 20k records coming from Stage1 table in  DB. In a batch step I am trying to migrate these records to STG2 table. The problem I am facing is the order in which the records are getting inserted is changing. Maintaining the sequence is important . Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably by default 16 threads works in parallel, also the default batch size is 100. Try the for each instead of batch and it should resolve your issue.

Comment: You could also try to reduce the batch size to 1 and that should work as well.

Comment: Tried reducing  the batch size to 1....till around 62 records it works fine after that it is loosing the sequence

Comment: Do you have may batch process steps? Then try the for each and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to interate through the list and insert records one by one?

If Yes, then use foreach or collection splitter, it will process records in sequence.

If you want to insert records as a batch, then directly use a database connector and check bulk mode and insert the records.

Answer (score 0):

After 3.8, Mule allows you to configure the block size in the batch job properties tab. If you request fewer than batch size records, then your processing becomes sequential.

Reference: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/batch-processing